# Where can I find boolean feature in modifier for NURBS?

Tags: modeling

I created 2 nurbs. One sphere and one plane. I try to add boolean in Modifier. But I can not find boolean feature in list Modifier feature.
Please view attached file for more details.

[image]

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AuAcyL2kNiCPg7oc953FjKr7rbleiA?e=swevuo

Answer (score 2):

The boolean modifier is only available for meshes.

You would have to convert your nurbs objects to meshes.  Probably not what you wanted to hear.

This is something I miss from Rhino and other modellers.  In blender, however, the mesh is king.

Comment: I made some model in Rhino. It's great NURBS softwares but can not come back when you did boolean. I'm looking other NURBS software and find Blender. But Now I find out It have modifier but there's no boolean.

Comment: If this has resolved your question ( but not your hopes ) please mark the solution as accepted so others know that this has been resolved.