# NURBS convert to MESH and reverse operation

Tags: nurbs-surface

I encoutered the same problem asked by @Travis [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/160352/where-can-i-find-boolean-feature-in-modifier-for-nurbs), and I applied the solution proposed by @Moog.

I tried thus to convert NURBS Sphere to MESH and delete Vertex, but when I tried to perform the reverse operation, I loose the object (see below).

[image]

Is there a solution for this ?

Thanks a lot in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it doesn't work because in Blender curves control points can't be linked to more than 2 other control points. This is a limitation and I don't think you can do much about it, the software can't guess which edges you want to keep. What you can do is extract the vertical and horizontal edge rings, and then convert to a curve.

Illustration :

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the .gif but it's too quick for me. I don't succed to apply what you did. How do you move the selected vertical and horizontal Edges ? Is there several copies of the inital MESH ? Please, could you also send me a link to better understand this : "control points can't be linked to more than 2 other control points." Thanks again.

Comment: For information, I found this : https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65061/mesh-curve-to-nurbs?rq=1

Comment: @arum ALT + Click on Edge ring, then Select > Select Loops > Edge Rings then SHIFT D to duplicate and H to hide. Then do the same for the horizontal rings, duplicate, hide, delete the base meshj and you only have unconnected edges. You won't go back to NURBS though, only regular curves

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot convert a surface to a curve without losing data AFAIK. I think you meant to convert to mesh.